# mongoDB TypeError when trying to search in database

Tags: mongodb

I have a big database with many documents in one collection. When i use `findOne()`. It gives me this

```
> db.sem.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56619c6852a9c022d077400b"),
        "name" : "MANAN VIJAY",
        "reg_no" : "11011",
        "dept" : "B.Tech",
        "subjects" : {

    },
    "sem" : "5"
}
```

now when I try

```
> db.cse_sem_5.find()(
... {"name": "MANAN VIJAY"}
... )
2015-12-08T14:24:21.052+0530 E QUERY    TypeError: object is not a function
at (shell):1:20
```

Why am I getting this error? And how can I resolve it?
This did not happen when I tried something with a smaller database..

Comment: As Sarath Nair pointed out, your problem is that you have empty parentheses after `find`, remove them and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your find() query looks wrong, try like this:

```
db.cse_sem_5.find({"name": "MANAN VIJAY"})
```

Comment: crap, that was very stupid of me.. i looked at it thousands of times and still couldn't figure it out